# DOM reloads when using Jquery drag and drop

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, draggable, droppable

We are making an interactive story for our school project. But we get a problem, when you get to the stage where you have to build a Lego-man. When you drag one of the body parts onto the grey area, it seems to reset the DOM, or refresh it.

Can anyone see what is going on?

You can see the "game" on this link.

http://mikkellindblom.dk/tommy-LEGO/

------ Sorry for no code!!! ----- I don't know which part I should post, and and not even sure if it is the DOM that resets.

Comment: Works fine for me. Passed the level, yeay!

Comment: It does not "blink" when you snap the head to the head-grey space?

Comment: I passed the first level with no reload too. I'm such a great player...
I was using the last version of firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing your DOM element re-drawing, Win7/Chrome.  Your code is so buried inside AJAX fragments, it took awhile to track things down, but I think what's happening is that when you are successfully dropping the item -- it's also registering as a click event, and on that page, you do have a click event :

```
// Level 2 handeler
        $("#level-2").click(function(){
           if ( $( this ).hasClass( "active" ) ) {
           $( "#level_holder" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
           $( "#loader" ).fadeIn();
           $( "#content_holder" ).load('content/content-2.html');
           $( "#content_holder" ).fadeIn();
           $( "#loader" ).fadeOut();
           } else {
            swal({ title: "Hov!", text: "Du skal klare level 1 først!", type: "error", confirmButtonText: "Okay" });
           }
        });
```

So you might want to try, in your drag-droppable drop event, to prevent event bubbling further.   In this part, add some code to prevent the click event to continue on bubbling:

```
function handleItemDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var itemNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );
  // Hvis delen er placeret i den korrekte ramme.
  if ( slotNumber == itemNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctItems++;
  } 
  // Antallet af dele der er placeret korrekt = 3 (total = 3), load nÃ¦ste side.
  if ( correctItems == 3 ) {
    $( "#main" ).load('content/fragments-1/fragment-3.html');
  }
 event.stopPropagation(); // <-- stops the 'click' event firing, reloading your "page".
}
```

Here's a link to jQuery event handling:
http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

So - in short, I think when you successfully drop an object, it's also firing the page's click event which ends up redrawing that fragment.  Essentially, add `event.stopPropagation()` at the end of your `handleItemDrop` function and see if that doesn't stop the refreshing of that DOM fragment (it's not so much refreshing as redoing the fadeOut and fadeIn again).